# Submitting form, with JavaScript with no Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit

I have a script, that does:
 1. Check when iframe is 100% loaded. 
 2. Then when iframe is loaded, a progress bar/countdown appear.
 3. When the countdown hits 0, **I want to do a $_POST of the current page, but I want to do it without a submit button or anything else.**

Here is my code:

```
// on document load:
$(function() {
   // set "waiting" message:
   $("#loadingStatus").html("Waiting for your advertisements to load...");

   // on iframe load:
   $('#iFrame').load(function() {

       $("#loadingStatus").html($("#isDone").html());



   });
});

$(function count() {
   var seconds = <?php echo $exposure[$r['exposure']]; ?>;
   setTimeout(updateCountdown, 1000);

   function updateCountdown() {
      seconds--;
      if (seconds > 0) {
         $("#countdown").text("You have " + seconds + " seconds remaining");
         setTimeout(updateCountdown, 1000);
      } else {
         submitForm();
      }
   }
});

        $(function submitForm() {
            $('form').submit(function(){
                $('#status').hide();
                $.post(
                    '?i=v&p=k&key=DSF79SADFHSA7D9FGSAD097FSAD7F9779ASDFGS9', 
                    $('form').serialize(),
                    function (data) {
                        proccessData(data);
                    }
                );
                return false;    
            });
        });

        function proccessData (data) {
            $('#status').hide().html('');

            if(data=='success'){
                $('form').fadeOut();
                $('#status').addClass('noti-success').html('You have successfully viewed this advertisement.').slideDown();
                redirect("?i=l");
            }
            else {
                $('#status').addClass('noti-error').html(data).fadeIn();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is traditional here to accept previously given answers (where they have solved your problem) by clicking on the tick alongside said answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do a `document.forms.formName.submit()`

Comment: If I do that, how will I then show either error or success codes without doing a page refresh?